# Cgal surface mesh - connectivity

Tags: c++, mesh, cgal

I am bit confused how does connectivity work.
I am trying to remove face from mesh, and adjust connectivity, remove unusued edges and vertices.
When i use   ***mesh.is_valid()*** it shows me connection problems

> Integrity of previous halfedge of h1 corrupted. Halfedge of v0 is not
>   an incoming halfedge.  vertices: iterated: 1 vs number_of_vertices():
>   5 halfedges: iterated: 2 vs number_of_halfedges(): 14 faces: iterated:
>   3  vs number_of_faces(): 3

Code:

```
#include <string>
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Gmpq.h>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;

typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<K::Point_3> Mesh;
typedef Mesh::Vertex_index vertex_descriptor;
typedef Mesh::Face_index face_descriptor;
typedef Mesh::Halfedge_index halfedge_descriptor;
typedef Mesh::Edge_index edge_descriptor;

int main()
{
  Mesh mesh;
  vertex_descriptor v0 = mesh.add_vertex(K::Point_3(0,2,0));
  vertex_descriptor v1 = mesh.add_vertex(K::Point_3(2,2,0));
  vertex_descriptor v2 = mesh.add_vertex(K::Point_3(0,0,0));
  vertex_descriptor v3 = mesh.add_vertex(K::Point_3(2,0,0));
  vertex_descriptor v4 = mesh.add_vertex(K::Point_3(1,1,0));
  mesh.add_face(v3, v1, v4);
  mesh.add_face(v0, v4, v1);
  mesh.add_face(v0, v2, v4);
  mesh.add_face(v2, v3, v4);

 int counter = 0;
 std::vector <edge_descriptor> edg;
 BOOST_FOREACH(face_descriptor fd, mesh.faces()){
  if(counter == 0){
    halfedge_descriptor hed = mesh.halfedge(fd);
    halfedge_descriptor prev = mesh.prev(hed);
    halfedge_descriptor next = mesh.next(hed);

    mesh.set_vertex_halfedge_to_border_halfedge (next);
    mesh.set_vertex_halfedge_to_border_halfedge (prev);
    mesh.set_vertex_halfedge_to_border_halfedge (hed);

    if(mesh.is_border(mesh.opposite(next))){
      mesh.remove_edge(mesh.edge(next));
      std::cout << "Remove next halfedge " << next << std::endl;
    }else{
      mesh.set_face(next, mesh.null_face());
      std::cout << "sets next halfedge " << next << std::endl;
    }

    if(mesh.is_border(mesh.opposite(prev))){
      mesh.remove_edge(mesh.edge(prev));
      std::cout << "Remove prev halfedge " << prev << std::endl;
    }else{
      mesh.set_face(prev, mesh.null_face());
      std::cout << "sets prev halfedge " << prev << std::endl;
    }
    if(mesh.is_border(mesh.opposite(hed))){
      mesh.remove_edge(mesh.edge(hed));
      std::cout << "Remove Face halfedge " << hed << std::endl;
    }else{
      mesh.set_face(hed, mesh.null_face());
      std::cout << "sets Face halfedge " << hed << std::endl;
    }
    mesh.remove_face(fd);
    counter++;

    }
  }
  mesh.collect_garbage();
  mesh.is_valid();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you briefly explain each of your three edge operations and your reasoning behind them?

Comment: First im making each halfedge to border halfedge, with set_vertex_halfedge to border halfedge, afterwards i check if opposite halfedge is border. if opposite halfedge is border, then i remove the edge,if not then i set face of that halfedge to null_face. afterwards when i have done it, i remove face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`remove_face`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLEulerOperations.html#gacfae7ff8e782da55b941e4487e86c738) function of the [Euler operations](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLEulerOperations.html). It will "maintain the validity" behind the scenes for you. The Euler operations work on values of any type `Graph` that is "a model of" [`MutableFaceGraph`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/classMutableFaceGraph.html). Fortunately, your [`SurfaceMesh`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh/classCGAL_1_1Surface__mesh.html) is such a model.

If you replace your loop (which is unnecessary since you just want one face) with the following, you will see how it works:

```
int counter = 0;
BOOST_FOREACH(face_descriptor fd, mesh.faces()){
  counter++;
}
std::cout << counter << " faces" << std::endl;

CGAL::Euler::remove_face(mesh.halfedge(*mesh.faces().begin()), mesh );
mesh.collect_garbage();
mesh.is_valid();

counter = 0;
BOOST_FOREACH(face_descriptor fd, mesh.faces()){
  counter++;
}
std::cout << counter << " faces" << std::endl;
```

This produces no validation errors and confirms that there is one fewer face in the mesh after the operation.